# I want to click on a checkbox using selenium but no method is working for me

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, mechanize, beautifulsoup

```
<input type="hidden" name="vendor_service[customized_car_types[]][is_checked]">
<input type="checkbox" name="vendor_service[customized_car_types[]][is_checked]">== $0
<b>Sedan</b>
```

i want to click on the check box, when i hover over the box the 2nd line of html is highlighted. How can I click on the box with this?

Comment: Please add the code where you started doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a css selector, for example:

```
input[type=checkbox][name*=vendor_service]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ActionChains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="vendor_service[customized_car_types[]][is_checked]"]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(checkbox)
actions.click()
actions.perform()
```

Note, that for now this approach doesn't work in `Firefox` (`geckodriver`)

Comment: I tried your code and I didn't get any error, but it didn't work too. There are 4 checkboxes and each one has these two lines of code when I hover on them but what is making them unique is the line below the two lines specifying the type. Below these two lines there is a line - <b>Sedan</b> if that can help you making the code more efficient then please try and tell me.. Thanks for answer anyways

Comment: Lets make it clear. Initially there is `<input type="hidden">`, right? When you hover mouse pointer over it, it changed to `<input type="checkbox">` or both elements are available?

Comment: Nothing actually changes, there are these two lines inside <td> the type hidden has no effect but when I hover on the second line, the check box is highlighted

Comment: try `checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="vendor_service[customized_car_types[]][is_checked]" and @type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: should I add .click() ?

Comment: Error - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name="vendor_service[‌​customized_car_types‌​[]][is_checked]" and @type="checkbox"]"}`

Comment: If i right click on the second line of code and get the xpath it gives - `//*[@id="new_vendor_service"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input[2]`

Comment: Can you share `URL`?

Comment: No, its backend actually, id and pw will be required to view the page

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the checkbox is 'underneath' another element. Try interacting directly with the javascript on the page. You could try something like:

```
void clickElementWithJs(WebDriver driver, String cssSelector) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Apologies, my solution is in java.

Comment: I am using python, sorry I didn't mention

Answer (score 0):

Is the check box visible?

I remember running into an issue where my script would fail to check a check-box that was visible on the page by default but not currently in view. Once I scrolled down and it was visible, that command worked as it should.